# soap header exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: {"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."}]

when i am trying to consume the wcf service for insert only , i am getting this error. remaining select and delete query is working properly .

Comment: Have you tried either of the suggestions the error message gave you?  Turning on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults or enabling WCF Tracing?

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is not much explaining enough. What you can do for time being is, to decorate your Service contract with this `[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]`

This will dive you details about the exception error.